# Import function variables from one python file to another

Tags: python, scope

I wanted to import a variable defined in function to another python file

e1.py

```
 def abc():
     global a
     a=10
```

e2.py

```
import e1
def defi():
    c=e1.abc.a
    print(c)

defi()
```

I have searched but didn't get the right answer

Following is the error-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\gkaur\Documents\MSO Editor Tool\e2.py", line 1, in <module>
 from e1 import abc
 File "C:\Users\gkaur\Documents\MSO Editor Tool\e1.py", line 2
 global a
 SyntaxError: name 'a' is parameter and global
```

Comment: If it's a global variable, then you should be able to import it directly from the file.  It will not include the setting made in `abc()` because this is a `runtime` setting.

Comment: if importing the file gives you an error, generally trying to import anything from it will give you an error.  You should fix the error.  Also, using global variables is generally frowned upon...

Comment: I have tried that too.. just writing `print a` but it still gives an error

Comment: Well, whatever ***that error is***, that's your first problem.  Fix that.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix that is why I have posted here because I am not able to resolve it

Comment: There's no module called `e1` shown. Are these files named "e1.py" and and "e2.py" or "file1.py"and "file2.py"?  Also, `abc` has no attribute named "a".

Comment: @saulspatz its actually e1.py and e2.py. But here I have mistakenly written file and file 2. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the function in file 1 correctly it should be:

```
def abc():
    a = 10
    return a
```

You should be returning the value. for the second file it should be:

```
import e1
def defi():
    c = e1.abc()
    print(c)

defi()
```

without the `()` at the end of `e1.abc()` it doesn't actually tell the function to perform it's specific task.

Comment: it still give an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gkaur\Documents\MSO Editor Tool\e2.py", line 8, in <module>
    defi()
  File "C:\Users\gkaur\Documents\MSO Editor Tool\e2.py", line 4, in defi
    c=e1.a()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'`

Comment: so there is no variable named `a` in your file then remove the line `global a`

Comment: this doesn't work too :( `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gkaur\Documents\MSO Editor Tool\e2.py", line 8, in <module>
    defi()
  File "C:\Users\gkaur\Documents\MSO Editor Tool\e2.py", line 4, in defi
    c=e1.a()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
>>> `

Comment: oh why are you doing `e1.a()` it's supposed to be the name of the function which is `abc()`, so it should be `e1.abc()` e1 is the file and abc() is the function

Comment: No problem. Have fun programming!

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a module global variable in `e1`. Other than being set in `abc`, it is unrelated to that function; `abc.a` is an error.

```
import e1
def defi():
    c = e1.a
    print(c)

# This should produce an error
defi()
```

However, unless you give `a` a value in the global scope of `e1`, it does not exist until you call `abc`.

```
import e1
def defi():
    c = e1.a
    print c

e1.abc()
defi()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `a` is not defined until you call `abc()`.

As you can see with `dir(e1)` or `help(e1)` in a repl, `e1` does not have a variable `a`, only a function `abc`.  Then after a call to `abc()`, `a` is here and set to 10.

```
>>> import e1
>>> dir(e1)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abc']
>>> e1.abc()
>>> dir(e1)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'a', 'abc']
>>> e1.a
10
```